# Keeping circles from overlapping

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, geometry

I'm trying to figure out the JavaScript math to move two colliding circles apart from each other.

The left side of this image is a visual representation of what I already have:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FMv1G3O.png]

<sup>x1, y1, x2 and y2 are the positions of the circles, r1 and r2 are the radii of the circles, theta is the angle between the circles in relation to the x-axis of the canvas.</sup>

**How do I calculate the new [x,y] positions for both circles, so that they "push" each other apart as demonstrated on the right side of the image?**

I'm also planning to make the smaller circle be pushed more than the larger one. That should be easy enough by using their normalized radii as a multiplier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Just take the vector difference between the centers
var dx = x2 - x1;
var dy = y2 - y1;

// compute the length of this vector
var L = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

// compute the amount you need to move
var step = r1 + r2 - L;

// if there is a collision you will have step > 0
if (step > 0) {
    // In this case normalize the vector
    dx /= L; dy /= L;

    // and then move the two centers apart
    x1 -= dx*step/2; y1 -= dy*step/2;
    x2 += dx*step/2; y2 += dy*step/2; 
}
```